# Reorder specific rows of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hello All and Thanks in Advance

This is my problem. I have to sort tables. One table has say total 10 rows. 3 top rows of that tables have fixed values. I want to sort the remaining 7 rows values alphabetically on the basis of first column input.

The other table has same structure. That is first column of the table has an input of type text. But in this table the problem is complex i.e. there are total 12 rows. First 2 rows are fixed. They are not going to move. And also the last row is also fixed. The remaining in between needs to be sorted alphabetically again on the basis of input in the first column.

Third table is the easiest I guess. No rows are fixed. Neither at top nor at bottom. And the rows needs to be sorted.

The table structure that I am following is as follows

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column One Heading</th>
      <th>Column Two Heading</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='A fixed value' id='Heading' /></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='1' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Table Footer</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Kindly note that i do not want the reordering of the table rows. I only want the values inside the first two columns reordered in the rows and rows don't move. Which essentially means the hidden value of a particular row is not changed.

I don't know how to do it but what i feel is right way to go about it is fetch the values of the rows that needs to be sorted into say a JSON Array. Sort that array and then fill the rows with the data.

### First Example

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column One Heading</th>
      <th>Column Two Heading</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>

    <td> <input type='text' value='A fixed value' id='Heading1' disabled='disabled' /></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='1' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='A fixed value' id='Heading2' disabled='disabled'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='2' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='A fixed value' id='Heading3' disabled='disabled'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='3' />
    </td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading4'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='4' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading5'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='5' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading6'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='6' />
    </td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading7'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='7' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading8'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='8' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading9'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='9' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading10'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='10' />
    </td>
  </tr>


</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Table Footer</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

### Second Example

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column One Heading</th>
      <th>Column Two Heading</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>

    <td> <input type='text' value='A fixed value' id='Heading1' disabled='disabled' /></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='1' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='A fixed value' id='Heading2' disabled='disabled'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='2' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='A fixed value' id='Heading3' disabled='disabled'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='3' />
    </td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading4'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='4' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading5'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='5' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading6'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='6' />
    </td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading7'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='7' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading8'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='8' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading9'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='9' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading10' value='A fixed value' disabled='disabled'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='10' />
    </td>
  </tr>


</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Table Footer</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

### Third Example

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column One Heading</th>
      <th>Column Two Heading</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>

    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading1' /></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='1' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading2' /></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='2' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading3'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='3' />
    </td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading4'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='4' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading5'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='5' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading6'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='6' />
    </td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading7'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='7' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading8'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='8' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading9'/></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='9' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' id='Heading10' /></td>
    <td> 
      <input type='number' value='' id='Amount' />
      <br />
      <input type='hidden' value='10' />
    </td>
  </tr>


</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Table Footer</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post tables withe example data

Comment: Well if i post only 1 table here it goes over the limit. Let me try to trim down the table and post only the rows.

Comment: I am adding only rows and that too just 5 for problem 1

Comment: You can put it in JSFiddle as well..

Comment: Okay let me try. I have never used JSFiddle. But let me give it a try

Comment: Okay i have managed to edit my post and put the complete tables structure there.

Comment: are you specifying which fields are static by disabling them?

Answer (score 0):

heres something real quick:

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/tcy0tmb5/

**JS**

```
function sortColumn(staticRowCount, columnToSort) {
    var values = [];
    $('tr').each(function(index, element) {
        if (index > staticRowCount) {
            var td = $(element).find('td').get(columnToSort);
            values.push($(td).find('input').val());
        }
    });

    //Do the sort
    values.sort;

      $('tr').each(function(index, element) {
        if (index > staticRowCount) {
            var val = values.shift();
            //if you want to pull form the other side of the array use pop();
            var td = $(element).find('td').get(columnToSort);
            $(td).find('input').val(val);
        }
    });
}


sortColumn(3, 0);
```

Comment: I tried it in JSFiddle in the url you provided. But it is not working for me.

Comment: Just add `sortColuimn(3,1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a specific class to all the elements that needs to be ordered.
If you just want to order the first elements value you can use this code, after adding a "toBeOrdered" class to the elements:

```
var objs = document.getElementsByClassName("toBeOrdered");
var array = [];
for ( var i = 0 ; i < objs.length ; i++ ) {
    array[i] = objs[i].value;
}
array.sort();
for ( var i = 0 ; i < objs.length ; i++ ) {
     objs[i].value = array[i];
}
```

Comment: can you do it on JSFiddle and pass me the link ?

Comment: Here it is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mpyavkc9/ (it changes just the value of the element, for switching the entire elements you need to do the sorting yourself with algorithm such as bubblesort, quiksort, ecc. and switch the elements along with the values while sorting)

Comment: It works like a charm ! I will try to integrate it today and hopefully I won't need any more help. but from the demo on JSFiddle it works fine. I need to deliver this by day end tomorrow so keeping my fingers crosses !!! I tried to vote up your solution but i am not eligible !!!

Comment: There are some issues. I have been trying to fix them but unable to do so. Issue 1) If i enter only 2 new rows and sort them. The rows are sorted from bottom. However they should be sorted right after the fixed rows. And only column 1 values are sorted. Adjacent Column 2 values are not sorted and remain as it is. They should also be sorted according to column 1

Comment: It only works fine i.e. first column gets sorted when all the rows are filled

Comment: Hy, just saw the problems, sorry for this, here it is a solution for both the problems: https://jsfiddle.net/mpyavkc9/1/